# DropBox / Google Drive stopped working simultaneously

Tags: windows-7, dropbox, google-drive

I noticed recently that both DropBox and Google Drive stopped syncing several days ago on my desktop at work (Win 7 64 bit). The last successful sync for both was sometime on Sep 30. At first both services had a perpetual "Connecting..." message, and when I tried reconnecting my account, I got different errors: DropBox says that there's no internet connection, and Google Drive tells me that my login credentials are wrong. I also have OneDrive installed, and that still updates just fine.

My work laptop (Win 7 64 bit) has the same problems. My personal laptop (Win 7 32 bit) is syncing just fine. I checked the Windows Updates log, and the last update was on Sep 23, so that doesn't seem to be part of the problem.

I tried all of the suggestions on [this](https://www.dropbox.com/en/help/72) page, with no success.

My work machines have different programs running constantly than my personal computer, including the antivirus software, Check Point encryption and Track-IT. Disabling the antivirus software had no effect. It's possible that the latter two could have done something, but they've been there for years and haven't caused any problems before, and to my knowledge were not updated recently.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: I may be completely wrong, but that sounds as if your workplace has blocked dropbox and google drive at the firewall

Comment: Ah, that does seem to be the case. I just tested the work laptop at my home, and it worked fine. Thanks.

Comment: @Fegnoid could you post your comment as answer so Jon can mark it as answer? This way, this question won't keep showing up as unanswered. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It most probably the firewall at your workplace blocking them